# how to join the input from every row and save to database

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox, codeigniter-2

i have this problem

this is the display from my view.php

```
id menu  +1 +2 +3

 1   bla_1 [] [] []
 2   bla_2 [] [] []
 3   bla_3 [] [] []
```

and this is my view code

```
<?php $i=1; foreach ($test as $row) : ?>
<tr>
<td><input type='hidden' name='id[]' value="<?php echo $row->menu_id ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Menu" value="<?php echo $row->menu_nama ?>" disabled <td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'menu_id[]'; ?>" value="+1"  /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'menu_id[]'; ?>" value="+2"  /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'menu_id[]'; ?>" value="+3"  /></td>
</tr>
<?php $i++; endforeach ; ?>
```

if i check the first checkbox i will get +1, the second checkbox i will get +2

my goal is to join the input from every checked checkbox and save to database based on id

and this is my code on model to join the value of checkbox

```
$menu_id= $this->input->post('menu_id');        
        $menu_idc = '';

        $count = count($menu_id);
        $i=0;
        foreach($menu_id as $e){ 
            if($i < $count -1)
            {
                $menu_idc .= $e.'';
                echo $i ;
            }
            else{
                $menu_idc .= $e.'+';
                }
                $i++;
            }
            var_dump($menu_idc);
            die;
```

from example if i check this checkbox

```
         id menu   +1   +2  +3

         1   bla_1 [v] [v] [v]
         2   bla_2 []  [v] []
         3   bla_3 []  []  [v]
```

with code i write i will get +1+2+3+2+3+  (+1+2+3 from row 1, +2 from row 2, +3 from row 3)

what i want is to get is value from every row and save to table on database

+1+2+3+ save into database

+2+ save into database

+3+ save into database

```
    Database
id   | isi     |
1    | +1+2+3+ |
2    | +2+     |
3    | +3+     |
```

i think i must loop the code on my model but i dont know what code i have to write

Comment: what do you mean by each row? What query have you tries. php implode() can help you

Comment: @raheelshan sorry i mean based on id, i just edit my question

Comment: you are looping and providing menu_id to multiple chechboxes with the same values. Do this instead <?php echo "menu_id_$i[]"; ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension is for the row and the second one is for the columns.

First change your markup a bit to make the submitted values 2-dimensional:

```
<?php $i=1; foreach ($test as $row) : ?>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='hidden' name="menu[<?php echo $i ?>][id]" value="<?php echo $row->menu_id ?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="menu[<?php echo $i ?>][menu]" value="<?php echo $row->menu_nama ?>" disabled <td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="menu[<?php echo $i ?>][plus][]" value="+1"  /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="menu[<?php echo $i ?>][plus][]" value="+2"  /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="menu[<?php echo $i ?>][plus][]" value="+3"  /></td>
  </tr>
<?php $i++; endforeach ; ?>
```

This code should work fine:

```
$menus = $this->input->post('menu');        

foreach ($menus as $menu)
{
  $id = $menu['id'];
  $name = $menu['name'];
  $menu_ids = "";

  if (is_array($menu['plus']))
  {
    $menu_ids = join('', $menu['plus'])).'+';
  }

  // here you can save it now by executing a sql update or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a 2-dimensional array, the first dimension is the row, the second dimension is the checkboxes. In the form, you should have:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'menu_id['.$row->menu_id.'][]'; ?>" value="+1"  /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'menu_id['.$row->menu_id.'][]'; ?>" value="+2"  /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'menu_id['.$row->menu_id.'][]'; ?>" value="+3"  /></td>
```

Then in your processing script, you can do:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['id'] as $id)
  $isi[$id] = implode('', $menu_id[$id]);
```